# Catching a moment when some specific "laggy" application window finishes processing its keyboard input

Tags: c#, winapi, input, keyboard, sendkeys

I want to show a popup when I get some specific input **I** into any currently running application **A**. Depending on popup's dialog result, I want to modify the text into application **A**'s current textbox by sending keystrokes using SendKeys class. I'm currently using low level keyboard hook, which means I could get keydown events before application **A** process it. In this case my popup will be shown before last part of the inputted text appears in the **A**'s text box. Popup will get the focus and prevent this part of text from reaching **A**.

For example, I'm searching for **lol** keyword. User opens Notepad and inputs "lol". My application should show popup window "Press Enter to add blahblahblah text" at this moment. Popup window became foreground. If user presses Enter, application closes this dialog, makes Notepad foreground back again and sends "blahblahblah" as a keystrokes to the system.

Everything works fine with the Notepad, but what if target application/system works slowly and not responding sometimes? Considering the next test app:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    timer1.Enabled = true;
    timer1.Interval = 2000;
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Join(1900);
}
```

This form contains a textbox and its UI thread is sleeping 95% of the time. It processing keyboard input each 2 seconds. So if user inputs **lol** in such a window, my application most likely will show the popup before "lol" text appears in the textbox.

I do not want to show my popup before all the text reached the target app **A**.
Can you please suggest any method of getting the moment when some process consumed all the keyboard input?

SendKeys.Flush() is not working for me. So does Process.WaitForInputIdle(), which is designed for other purpose, I suppose. I've tried to send WM_ACTIVATE message via SendMessage to the target app, because I thought it's exactly what I'm looking for:

> The SendMessage function calls the window procedure for the specified
>   window and does not return until the window procedure has processed
>   the message.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

```
User32.SendMessage(activeWindow, WM_ACTIVATE, WA_ACTIVE, 0)
```

call returns 0, but not creating required pause and my popup appears before the text.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `SendMessage` does not wait its turn. In other words, it does not append a message to the **back** of a message queue, to act as a sentinel in your described scenario. Similarly, `PostMessage` will not work either: Posted messages are placed at the **front** of the message queue.

Comment: On top of that, you shouldn't be sending the `WM_ACTIVATE` message. That will freak apps out. (They will get activation messages when they are already activated and that's not supposed to happen.)

Comment: Hm, ok, thanks for answers. I've read this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6362/Global-System-Hooks-in-NET and going to try WH_KEYBOARD hook instead of WH_KEYBOARD_LL. I know all the drawbacks of that method, but why not give it a try. I hope this will help my app to coöperate with the target apps in a right manner.